# Auto does not work with stuctured binding

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand how structured bindings for custom types work in practice. The following code does not compile with an error:

```
error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘Customer&’ to an rvalue of type ‘Customer
```

I'm probably missing some fundamental understanding. If I either replace `auto` with `auto&` or `Customer&` to with `const Customer&` everything compiles fine. Why rvalue of Customer is mentioned in the error message?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

struct Customer
{
    int id = 10;
};

template<>
struct std::tuple_size<Customer> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1> {};

template<>
struct std::tuple_element<0, Customer>
{
    using type = int;
};

template<std::size_t id>
auto get(Customer& customer)
{
    if constexpr (id == 0)
    {
        return customer.id;
    }
}

int main() {
    Customer customer;
    auto [id] = customer; // Ouch, error
    std::cout << id;
}
```

Comment: You might be interested in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20201015-00/?p=104369

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object passed to `get` is defined to be an xvalue in your case, it's not `customer` directly.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding):

> A structured binding declaration first introduces a uniquely-named variable (here denoted by ***e***) to hold the value of the initializer, as follows:
>
> [Array case]
>
> Otherwise ***e*** is defined as if by using its name instead of [ identifier-list ] in the declaration.
> We use **E** to denote the type of the expression `e`.

> For each identifier, a variable whose type is "reference to `std::tuple_element<i, E>::type`" is introduced: lvalue reference if its corresponding initializer is an lvalue, rvalue reference otherwise. The initializer for the i-th variable is
>
> - `e.get<i>()`, if lookup for the identifier get in the scope of `E` by class member access lookup finds at least one declaration that is a function template whose first template parameter is a non-type parameter
> - Otherwise, `get<i>(e)`, where get is looked up by argument-dependent lookup only, ignoring non-ADL lookup.
>   In these initializer expressions, `e` is an lvalue if the type of the entity ***e*** is an lvalue reference (this only happens if the *ref-qualifier* is & or if it is && and the initializer expression is an lvalue) and an xvalue otherwise (this effectively performs a kind of perfect forwarding), `i` is a `std::size_t` prvalue, and `<i>` is always interpreted as a template parameter list.

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR;** Basically, `get` is called on a copy of `customer`(that has the value category of `xvalue`) and not on lvalue `customer` itself.

---

When you use `auto [id] = customer;`, it captures `customer` in a hidden variable(aka **dummy variable**) say `e`. Then the call to `get`is made on `e` which is a copy and has the value category of **rvalue**(xvalue to be specific in this case) and since an rvalue of type `T` cannot be bound to a non-const lvalue reference to `T`, we get the mentioned error.